# Сервер не обрабатывает запрос

Tags: c#, winforms, клиент-сервер

Имеется форма в программе-клиенте с текстбоксом и кнопкой. По нажатию на кнопку, создается соединение, и на сервер отправляется запрос, затем, сервер, обрабатывая этот запрос, отправляет данные клиенту. Клиент работает с этими данными и потом отправляет что-то на сервер. И сервер меняет значение в своих данных. Так все должно быть
На деле же, когда я нажимаю на кнопку, то программа-клиент встает и в диспетчере задач висит в состоянии "не отвечает", а на сервере выводится только сообщение о том, какой запрос пришел
запрос на сервере:

```
{
    response= Convert.ToString(card.money);
    data = new byte[256];
    bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    mesage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
    int minusMoney = Convert.ToInt32(mesage);
    card.money -= minusMoney;

}
```

кнопка в программе-клиенте:

```
// Устанавливаем IP-адрес и номер порта для подключения
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
int port = 8080;

// Создаем TCP-сокет и подключаемся к серверу
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(ip, port);

// Получаем сетевой поток для чтения и записи данных
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
string message = "plusMoney";

//отправляем ответ
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);



int moneyParse;
if (int.TryParse(money, out moneyParse))
{
    if (moneyParse <= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Введите число, большее нуля", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        message = textBox1.Text;
        data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        //DefaultForm defaultForm = (DefaultForm)this.Owner; // Получение ссылки на родительскую форму
        //DefaultForm.CardInstance.InsertMoney(moneyParse);
        //defaultForm.SetLabel(Convert.ToString(money)); // Обновление текста Label на родительской форме
        this.Close(); // Закрытие текущей формы
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Введите корректное число", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

}
```

Прошу вашей помощи

Comment: Сначала отправляете plusMoney, сервер считывает, а потом отправляете количество, которое сервер уже не считывает, не правильная логика, либо отправляйте всё одним разом (например: "plusMone=100", спарсить на сервере это будет крайне легко), либо меняйте логику сервера (советую начать с чего-то попроще). Либо уберите из своей программы сокеты, перейдите на HTTP